# Scripts execution order - Javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables, order-of-execution

I have a HTML file with several JS scripts :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <title>Application</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
        <script src="initMap.js"></script>
        <script src="CSVParsing.js"></script>
        <script src="nbCinemas.js"></script>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width:1000px; height:800px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"></div>
    </body>
```

My problem is that in my *nbCinemas.js* file, I am using a global variable that is supposed to have been initialised in *CSVParsing.js*... but it is not. The thing is, I think that my *CSVParsing.js* file is loading last. Here is the file:

```
var arrayData;
d3.csv("cinemas-a-paris.csv", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.lat = +d.lat;
        d.lng = +d.lng;
    });
    arrayData = data;
    print();
});
function print() {
    console.log("done");
}
```

In the console, "done" is the last thing written, even though there are other console.logs in my *nbCinemas.js* file.

Can you help me? Why is my *CSVParsing.js* file loading last? How can I force it into loading ***before*** *nbCinemas.js*?

Thank you!

Tom.

Comment: Check your network tab in the chrome console - that will show you when each JS is being loaded and you can definitively see if the last thing loaded

Comment: csv function is loading asynchron data. so it is not available at the moment you load nbCinemas.js

Comment: @TypedSource Well, I was sure it was because of that... Can we make sure that the data is loaded when we load nbCinemas.js ?

Comment: @TomFévrier create an event listener in second file and a event call in the csv ready state. if event is called the second script start on the event listener

Answer (score 0):

First, probably

```
d3.csv("cinemas-a-paris.csv", function(data) {
   data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.lat = +d.lat;
    d.lng = +d.lng;
   });
   arrayData = data;
   print();
});
```

Is something that is happening in async, so it is send to the event loop, and the "done"message is just show up without that the past function had been finished.

After that, the next file is loaded and initialized and occurs the problem that you have.

One way to deal with this is, verifying that your global variable exists and, if it does, loading dynamicly your next js file like this:

```
// checking out the variable...
if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') {
   // ...the variable is defined, so 
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = 'http(s)://yourWebSiteURl.com/..js/nbCinemas.js';
}
```

This way you might ensure that this one last file is loading just after your global variable already exists

Comment: You're very welcome! let me know if this is enough to solving your problem (:

Comment: i edited my answer just in case. It's more clear about the external js resource

Comment: Surely there is a better way... Is there really no other way?